# Query from mongoDB table using pymongo taking lot of memory

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i'm new to mongo db.

I have a database set up and a table which has around 20 million rows.

id   source dest  value
   1    12     123    abc
   2    10     435    mmn

and so on.

I tried to connect it using pymongo package in python.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['test'] #name of db
stos_table = db['stos']  #stos is table_name which has 20 million rows
```

when i ran the query:

```
result = stos_table.find_one({'source':10,'dest':435})
```

My memory usage increased by 37 % ( it took approximately 6gb of my ram)
**Please tell why**???

(I guess it loaded entire table in memory)

Also the query execution took 10 seconds to run.

I actually wanted something like my load should be on database not on memory.

Is there any way where i can run similary query without loading entire data in memory and also get the result in milliseconds?

Is it possible with mongodb?

Comment: For your first question, the collection isn't loaded in application memory. To remedy the slow query, create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on the source and dest field if one isn't created yet.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule But why does the memory consumption increases when i run .find_one ? approx 6 gb!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you whant to do with you'r data.
Try to use mongoDB aggregation. But if you need only query, and do nothing with data, i don't think you will be able to avoid saving all the data in variable.